# The service code stays out-of-data after app update

Tags: android, android-service

My project consists of a main project and two library projects. I am using the manifest merging. One of library projects has a service running in a separate process with intention that it gets used by other similar apps which include my framework.

I am experiencing a very strange behavior where even though I update code in the service part, my app is still using the previous old version of it. Reinstalling the app does not help either.

Does anyone know what is a cause of this problem and how to resolve it?

UPDATE: The problem occurs only if I use `startService(new Intent ("service action"))`

Comment: how is it in the previous "previous version" what signifies this? are you talking about the versionNumber as found in the manifest or are you talking about the database?

Comment: after changing the model classes, the following happend:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object`
as a consequence that the service part is still using the old version of the object while the rest of the app is using the new one.
Also, the logic changes in the service code are ignored.

Comment: Had similar behavior. When using library projects, better get used to often cleaning the Library / consuming project :(